# echo message that all files have been uploaded

Tags: php

I am uploading multiple file to folder using PHP.  after uploading has been completed i am getting browser message for each file uploaded.  My question is how can I just have message for all when completed and if there was an error just show which files did not upload.  here is my script below, and thanks in advance

```
<?php

// Count # of uploaded files in array
$total = count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name']);

// Loop through each file
for ($i = 0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    //Get the temp file path
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];

    //Make sure we have a filepath
    if ($tmpFilePath != "") {
        //Setup our new file path
        $newFilePath = "./upimages/" . $_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];

        //Upload the file into the temp dir
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            ?><script>alert('successfully uploaded');</script><?php
        } else {
            ?><script>alert('error while uploading file');</script><?php
        } 
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make a simple variable `$error` and `$succes`. You can display those after the matter (when your loop ends). I have now printed every error and succes seperatly, you can do whatever you want with those arrays.

```
<?php

$total = count($_FILES['filesToUpload']['name']);
$succes = [];
$error = [];
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
    $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];
    if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    $newFilePath = "./upimages/" . $_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];
        if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
            $succes[$_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i]] = true;
        }else{
            $errors[$_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i]] = true;
        } 
    }
}
foreach(array_keys($succes) as $suc){
    echo $suc." was succesfull";
}
foreach(array_keys($errors) as $error){
    echo $error." failed to upload";
}

?>
```

Comment: i was receiving `error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'for' (T_FOR) in /data/9/3/62/77/3714077/user/4129685/htdocs/trial1.php on line 6`

Comment: @INOH they forgot the missing closure on `$error = []`, I edited the answer. Reload it and try it again. You should have caught that btw and is something to note when learning PHP.

Comment: @Nytrix need to be a bit more careful and not miss important closure syntax. Sometimes people don't know how to handle that and errors. ;-)

Comment: Is there a way to list the files successfully uploaded on a new line (each file) instead of all on same line

Comment: @Fred-ii- Agreed, I'll keep my eye on that with the next answer I provide!

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this if you want to still do it with alerts, pass the names of the files to a variable according to success or fail, and include them in your alert once you exit the for loop.

```
$successfulmsg="Successfully uploaded: ";
    $failedmsg="error while uploading files: ";
          // Loop through each file
for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
//Get the temp file path
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['filesToUpload']['tmp_name'][$i];

//Make sure we have a filepath
if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
//Setup our new file path
$newFilePath = "./upimages/" . $_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];

//Upload the file into the temp dir
if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {

            $successfulmsg.=$_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];


    }
    else
    {
        $failedmsg.=$_FILES['filesToUpload']['name'][$i];
    } 
    }       
}

echo '<script>alert("'.$successfulmsg.'. And '.$failedmsg.'")</script>';
```